# Code coverage of web application outside integration tests

Tags: java, code-coverage, war

I have a web application (WAR packaging) running fine. It provides an ODATA service. We are in development and consumer applications are developed at the same time.

What I would like to see is which part of the code is used in practice when processing requests of the consumer applications.

Is it possible to visualize or get reports about which part of the java code was even run? Like getting test coverage reports, but not during integration tests.

What is the recommendation to address this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. Some code coverage tools, including [JaCoCo](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html) and [JMockit](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/CodeCoverage.html#standalone) (which I develop) support this scenario.